# Regex in Javascript extract and group set if characters between dates

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have the following list:

```
ID:26 09/21 17:03 13:47 13:14 06:57 09/22 18:01 13:47 13:13 07:00 09/23 17:46 14:12 13:35 07:17 09/24 16:15 13:17 12:45 07:08
```

I need to extract and group by dates like:

```
09/21 17:03 13:47 13:14 06:57
09/22 18:01 13:47 13:13 07:00
09/23 17:46 14:12 13:35 07:17
09/24 16:15 13:17 12:45 07:08
```

I've tried using `(\d+[/]\d+())` but it only extracts the dates like:

```
09/21
09/22
09/23
09/24
```

and then tried grouping by using `(\/[^:]+?.+?)\/` with the following results

```
/21 17:03 13:47 13:14 06:57 09/
/23 17:46 14:12 13:35 07:17 09/
```

where it's missing the middle groups

I'm just strating with regex and any heklp will be highly appreciatted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one.

`\d{2}\/\d{2}` -> this will match the date

`(\s\d{2}:\d{2})+` -> this will match the following times separated by space

```js
var str = 'ID:26 09/21 17:03 13:47 13:14 06:57 09/22 18:01 13:47 13:13 07:00 09/23 17:46 14:12 13:35 07:17 09/24 16:15 13:17 12:45 07:08';
var matches = str.match(/\d{2}\/\d{2}(\s\d{2}:\d{2})+/g);
console.log(matches)
```

Comment: One last question, how can I add the ID to each line like: "26 09/21 17:03 13:47 13:14 06:57",  "26 09/22 18:01 13:47 13:13 07:00","26 09/23 17:46 14:12 13:35 07:17","26 09/24 16:15 13:17 12:45 07:08"

Comment: @JairoRodriguez sorry for late reply, you could do another regex match to find the ID, & then add it inside the matches loop